# i am gettig Could not create service of type WatchingAwareVirtualFileSystem using GradleUserHomeServices.createVirtualFileSystem() this error

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, gradle

I have tried reinstalling jdk, removed android from platform folder and again added it
My development configuration
Jdk 8, Gradle 7, node js 14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK4Zb.png)

Comment: * What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type WatchingAwareVirtualFileSystem using GradleUserHomeServices.createVirtualFileSystem().
   > java.io.IOException: Access is denied
full error is this

Comment: Please add that comment to your original question, also, please consider adding more details about the environment, the code or program being executed etc.